# Is it correct to say that "we did not assume that a or b is positive." is equivalent to "we did not assume that a and b are both positive"?

Tags: logic

Given a is a real number.

> We did not assume that a is positive.

For me, that sentence means either a is positive or a is not positive.

But given a and b are real numbers.

I read a sentence that "we did not assume that a or b is positive." in my textbook.

I wonder what meaning it has.

Are they

> we did not assume that a or b is positive.

> we did not assume that a and b are both positive

equivalent to each other?

> Is it correct to say that
>
> "we did not assume that a or b is positive."
>
> is equivalent to
>
> "we did not assume that a and b are both positive"?

I built a truth table that showed "tautology"

So can we say that?

Comment: If this for practical purposes (making your meaning clear in a written publication, for example), I would phrase it as "No assumptions were made about the sign (positive, negative or neutral) of either a or b."

Comment: @Deepak I just wonder if "we did not assume that a or b is positive." is understood by me correctly.

Comment: If you delete the part "we did not assume that" from both statements, the answer will be clear.

Comment: @Deepak For me, "We did not assume that a is positive." means "either a is positive or a is not positive."

Comment: If you assume that a is positive and b is negative, then you’ve broken the first statement but not the second. They are not the same.

Comment: If we did not assume that a or b is positive, then a and b could both be nonpositive. On the other hand, if we did not assume that a or b are both positive, then either a or b or both could be nonpositive.

Comment: Technically, no. Practically yes. "A or B is pos" and "A and B are both pos" are different statements so the the statements we  didn't assume are different.  But as we *didn't* assume them they are both irrelevant (we didn't assume dragons ate our kittens either). But we had a reason for pointing out we weren't assuming anything about their sign. In gen, I'd use the first to just say "We don't know anything about the signs" but I'd use the second if I had a reason to specify "Notice they don't *both* have to be positive". (It almost implies, but doesn't, that one or the other must be pos.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are they
>
> > we did not assume that a or b is positive.
>
> > we did not assume that a and b are both positive
>
> equivalent to each other?

No, the top one means "we did not assume that either a or b is positive" and the bottom one means "we did not assume that both a and b are positive".

"Either a or b is positive" is satisfied by $a=1, b=-1$ or $a=-1, b=1$, but not by $a=-1, b=-1$.

"Both a and b are positive" is satisfied by $a=1$ and $b=1$, but not by $a=-1, b=1$.